# Testing STI Associations with Shoulda-Matchers & FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda, sti

I am having issues with getting a simple STI shoulda-matcher spec to pass correctly.

Here are the associations..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :practice_manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
end

class PracticeManager < User
    has_many :providers
end
```

..and my factories..

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@email.com" }
    sequence(:password) { |p| "thepassword123" }
    sequence(:password_confirmation) { |p| "thepassword123" }

    factory :user do
        email
        password
        password_confirmation
    end

    factory :practice_manager, parent: :user, class: 'PracticeManager' do
    end

    factory :provider_user, parent: :user, class: 'ProviderUser' do
    end

    factory :provider do
        sequence(:first_name) { |n| "Sally#{n}" }
        sequence(:last_name) { |n| "Harmon#{n}" }
        sequence(:npi) { |n| n.to_s.rjust(10, '0')}
        sequence(:sf_contact_ident) { |s| s.to_s.rjust(15, '0') }
        practice_manager
    end
end
```

..as well as the test I am trying to get to pass.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PracticeManager, type: :model do
    describe "Relationships" do
        it { should have_many(:providers).class_name('User').with_foreign_key(:user_id) }
    end
end
```

One thing I found is that I can get the test to pass if I add the `class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id` to the `has_many` side of the association, but I'm afraid it's a false positive. It doesn't seem right.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing your associations up.

To test the `has_many` within your PracticeManager model, you simply want:

```
RSpec.describe PracticeManager, type: :model do
  describe "Relationships" do
    it { should have_many(:providers) }
  end
end
```

If you want to test your Provider model, *then* you'd need the extra options:

```
RSpec.describe Provider, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:practice_manager).class_name('User').with_foreign_key(:user_id) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot! That was it.